# PieChart only shows one element

Tags: php, symfony, highcharts, foreach, dql

I have a table containing users, each user has a city.
I am using [ObHighchartsBundle](https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle) to display the number of users in each city

this is my code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $classes = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->findAll();

        $data= array();
        $stat=array();
        foreach($classes as $class) {

            $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM MyBundle:User u WHERE u.city = ?1");
            $query->setParameter(1, $class->getCity());


            if (!in_array($class->getCity(), $stat)) {
                array_push($stat,$class->getCity(),($query->getSingleScalarResult() *1)/1);
            }


        }
    array_push($data,$stat);
```

I am only getting the number of users in the first city, so seems like my `foreach` loop is not working well .. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure how Doctrine handles this, but it is nearly always a bad choice to perform SQL in a loop. If you want to get the amount of users per city, you are better off with something like:

`SELECT COUNT(*), city FROM User GROUP BY city`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code in case somebody needs it:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$classes = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->findAll();

$data= array();
$stat=array();
$hm=array();

$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM MyBundle:User u WHERE u.city = ?1");

foreach($classes as $class) {

    $query->setParameter(1, $class->getCity());

        if (!in_array($class->getCity(), $hm)) {

            unset($stat);
            $stat = array();
            array_push($stat, $class->getCity(), (int)$query->getSingleScalarResult());
            array_push($hm, $class->getCity());
            array_push($data,$stat);

        }

}
```